# gevent + concurrent.futures and SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, future, gunicorn, gevent, concurrent.futures

I'm running and `pyramid` app inside gunicorn container with gevent async workers,
one of endpoints is a long-pool endpoint pooling AMQP via `kombu`.

If the long pool withing 30s timeout returns some data from AMQP I need to save it to postgres before returning, now the question is:

Is it OK to start `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` in context on app running in gevent loop, and deal with SQLAlchemy sessions and data persistence inside a future submitted to executor?

Or am I completely wrong in my way of thinking?

PS DB driver is psycopg2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using `ThreadPoolExecutor` with `gevent` in my high-concurrent app I can confirm that this works fine.

But unnecessary if the DB Driver is already `gevent` "friendly" like: [psycogreen](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psycogreen/)